# My app crashes when I am calling the method from an other class

Tags: java, android

I have a problem and would be very happy if anyone is helpful!

This is the crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.elvigo.swedencup.vigor, PID: 29477
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:90)
   at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
   at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:549)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4551)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:234)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:230)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:226)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:222)
   at android.widget.TableRow.<init>(TableRow.java:60)
   at com.elvigo.swedencup.vigor.TeamScoreTableUI.addRows(TeamScoreTableUI.java:78)
   at com.elvigo.swedencup.vigor.TeamScoreTableUI.CalladdRows(TeamScoreTableUI.java:65)
   at com.elvigo.swedencup.vigor.Classes.MatchTableDataFeatching.onPostExecute(MatchTableDataFeatching.java:139)
   at com.elvigo.swedencup.vigor.Classes.MatchTableDataFeatching.onPostExecute(MatchTableDataFeatching.java:26)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

And the activity including the called method:

```
public class TeamScoreTableUI extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView TextBox;
FloatingActionButton PrevScreenBtn;
public static TableLayout ll;


public static TextView textView;
public static TableRow row;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.teamscoring);


    MatchTableDataFeatching process = new MatchTableDataFeatching();
    process.execute();


    TextBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextBox);
    PrevScreenBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.BackButton);

    PrevScreenBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();

        }
    });

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "FairPlayCup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);


}

public void CalladdRows(){

    addRows();

}


public void addRows() {



    //for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        Log.d("dataFeatchingDone", "done");

        row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("10");
        row.addView(textView);
        ll.addView(row, 1);
    //}

}
}
```

I've also tested the app in debug mode and i came to that it crashes at: row = new TableRow(this);

I am calling the "CalladdRows()" method.

I was calling the method with:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    Log.d("app", "onPostExecute");

    TeamScoreTableUI.TextBox.setText(this.dataParsed);

    TeamScoreTableUI TeamScoreTableUIAddRows = new TeamScoreTableUI();
    TeamScoreTableUIAddRows.CalladdRows();

}
```

The method is in TeamScoreTableUI and is called CalladdRows..

I would be very happy if someone could take the time and help!

Comment: It says:                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference. Make sure your object is not null...

Comment: Are you trying to call this method from another activity?

Comment: How are you calling method from other class? Can you update your answer with this information?

Comment: What object should not be null?

I called the method with:
  

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Log.d("app", "onPostExecute");

        TeamScoreTableUI.TextBox.setText(this.dataParsed);

        TeamScoreTableUI TeamScoreTableUIAddRows = new TeamScoreTableUI();
        TeamScoreTableUIAddRows.CalladdRows();

    }

Comment: trying to understand your asyncTask workflow. ... you want to start a new activity when your asyncTask finish? you are calling "new TeamScoreTableUI()" which is a new activity. -> you will have problem initialising it (try using an intent to create the activity https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try with these changes:**

```
1. Pass context to your Task

MatchTableDataFeatching process = new MatchTableDataFeatching(this);

2. Get context in your Task

Context context;
public MatchTableDataFeatching(Context c) {
    context = c;
}
.......
3. Then in your onPost

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    ((TeamScoreTableUI)context).TextBox.setText(this.dataParsed);
    ((TeamScoreTableUI)context).CalladdRows();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my first problem, but now i've got a new one, at `ll.addView(row, 1);` My app crashes when executing that row.

Comment: I've found the problem! I just removed the child of `ll.addView(row, 1)`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
TeamScoreTableUI.TextBox.setText(this.dataParsed);

TeamScoreTableUI TeamScoreTableUIAddRows = new TeamScoreTableUI();
TeamScoreTableUIAddRows.CalladdRows();
```

you are creating a new activity wrongly, and calling "CalladdRows()" on this newly created activity (instead of using the same activity as the one you use to set "TextBox".

try changing your codes to

```
TeamScoreTableUI.TextBox.setText(this.dataParsed);       
TeamScoreTableUI.CalladdRows()
```

as a side note

The capital cases in your fields and method names makes the code difficult to read. I have problems figuring out if TeamScoreTableUI/TextBox inside your asyncTask is a field or a static class.

generally in JAVA, you use small letters (camelCase) for fields, variables and method names; and capital (PascalCase) for Classes.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tips! And thanks for the help!